# Problems restarting Apache - Curl related

Tags: php, apache-2.2, curl

I'm having a problem compiling LAMP, I have everything compiled and working, but when I try to restart apache I get the following error:

> seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process

And restart of apache aborts, I know is related with curl extension for php, as when i compile php without curl the error does not appear.  I've been looking a lot in Google, and found many similar questions, but none with an solution.

Comment: Any reason you're compiling it yourself and not using WAMP or a similar pre-packaged setup?

Comment: Boss orders. :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem, but sadly by a workaround.

As I told in the question, the problem was related to Curl, as when curl were complied with php I get the segmentation fault error,  Reading in Google I found that this error is common and dificult to solve :D, and related with php extension load order. So, the error may appear with any other module compiled.

The way I solved was taking Curl out from the compilation and loading it straight from php.ini, making a manual compilation of the Curl module and setting path to php modules default path, "/usr/local/lib" in my case.

After that, just adding:

```
extension="curl.so"
```

To php.ini file has solved the problem for me.

Hope it helps if any body found this question and have the same problem.